# Regex hangs forever

Tags: python, regex

`pattern = re.compile(r'((\s+?)?[\w\-)(]\s?){1,}:\s{0,}(n\/a|none)?$', re.IGNORECASE)`

I want this to match anything like:

```
Key:
Key Value(s):
  Key-Value:  
Key: none
Key value: n/a
```

But not match anything with a value:

```
Key-Value(s): Something
```

My expression works. But sometimes if the text I feed it is just regular text:

`A 46 year old man with no past medical or surgical presents with progressive left lower quadrant pain for 24 hours with no nausea or vomiting and normal non-bloody bowel function. No fever/chills.`

This hangs it up forever. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `(\s+?)?` is the same as `(\s*?)`

Comment: You're probably running into some kind of catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: I think because you are using a lot of optional parts and a quantifier inside a quantifier causing catastrophic backtracking. Perhaps try `^\s*[\w()-]+(?: [\w()-]+)?:(?: (?:none|n/a))?` https://regex101.com/r/5dzwR9/1

Comment: Try this `^[\w\-)(\s]*:\s*(n\/a|none)?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to catastrophic backtracking. `(...[\w\-)(\s]\s?){1,}` is faulty.

Use

```
^\s*(?:[\w()-](?:\s[\w()-])*)+\s*:\s*(?:n/a|none)?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Ww2Vxk/1)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w()-]                  any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '(', ')', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\w()-]                  any character of: word characters (a-
                               z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '(', ')', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    n/a                      'n/a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    none                     'none'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```